# Input switch requires double click before activating in Next.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js

i'm trying to make a on-off switch in Next.Js. For help i watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1W3mAtAT7os&t=740s
The Problem is, everytime i reload the page the switch requires 2 clicks before moving the switch and 3 clicks to turn it back off

here is the code in my .js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'    

export default function Navigation() {
    const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(false);

    const Toggle = ({onChange}) => 
        <label className='menu-button'>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} className='input'/>
            <span className='slider'/>
        </label>
        ;

    return (
        <div>
             <div className='menu-button-container'>
                  <Toggle onChange={(event) => setMenuActive(event.target.checked)} />
             </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.menu-button-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 125px;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
}

.input:checked + .slider:before {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 12.5px;
  background-position: center;
  left: 30px;
  content: "";
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 12.5px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where is Toggle import code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the checkbox value in your `<Toggle />` component!

This code should work:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Navigation() {
  const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(false);

  const Toggle = ({ onChange, value }) =>
    <label className='menu-button'>
      <input checked={value} type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} className='input' />
      <span className='slider' />
    </label>
    ;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='menu-button-container'>
        <Toggle value={menuActive} onChange={(event) => setMenuActive(event.target.checked)} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. The only Problem is now, that the slider doesn't animate its movement from left to right. Should i do it with className changing on usestate?

Answer (score 0):

Try with true value instead of false.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'    

export default function Navigation() {
    const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(true);

    const Toggle = ({onChange}) => 
        <label className='menu-button'>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} className='input'/>
            <span className='slider'/>
        </label>
        ;

    return (
        <div>
             <div className='menu-button-container'>
                  <Toggle onChange={(event) => setMenuActive(event.target.checked)} />
             </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```